# How to reference NuGet package in .csproj

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I need to use `<attrib>`  [[Docs]](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/attrib.html) element in the .csproj file of my .NET Framework console application.

It's nested in the `<Target Name="BeforeBuild">` element because I need to edit attributes of a few files before building, here is the full code from the .csproj:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Attrib Files="App.config" ReadOnly="false" />
    <Attrib Files="Ocelot.json" ReadOnly="false" />
    <Attrib Files="OcelotLogging.json" ReadOnly="false" />
</Target>
```

When the code is written as this, editor gives me this error: `Task 'Attrib' is not defined`.

**What have I tried?**

- I would use the `<UsingTask>` element, where the parameter is the path to the NAnt.Core NuGet package. Whole code looks like this:

  `<UsingTask TaskName="Attrib" AssemblyFile="C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\nant.core\0.92.0\lib\net40\NAnt.Core.dll" />
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      <Attrib Files="App.config" ReadOnly="false" />
      <Attrib Files="Ocelot.json" ReadOnly="false" />
      <Attrib Files="OcelotLogging.json" ReadOnly="false" />
  </Target>`
  But the error doesn't dissapear. When I try to compile the application anyway, I got following error: `The "Attrib" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\nant.core\0.92.0\lib\net40\NAnt.Core.dll. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing NAnt and MSBuild tasks.

NAnt tasks are written on a .build file and called by passing this file to the NAnt executable like explained [here](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/introduction/fog0000000041.html). You load them with [`loadtasks`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/loadtasks.html).

[MSBuild tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-tasks?view=vs-2019) however can be used like you want, in the .csproj file.
You use [`usingtask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/usingtask-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019) to work with them.

So in your case, what you can do is use the [msbuildtasks package](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) which also have an [`attrib`](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Documentation/TaskDocs.md#Attrib) task.

Install the package:

> The latest build can be downloaded from the releases section. https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/releases
>
> The MSBuild Community Tasks library is also available on nuget.org via package name > MSBuildTasks.
>
> To install MSBuildTasks, run the following command in the Package Manager Console
>
> `PM> Install-Package MSBuildTasks`

The installation also make sure you can then use the tasks in your csproj without needing to use `usingtask`, so:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Attrib Files="App.config" ReadOnly="false" />
    <Attrib Files="Ocelot.json" ReadOnly="false" />
    <Attrib Files="OcelotLogging.json" ReadOnly="false" />
</Target>
```

Note they are other way to do this with MSBuild, this one is only the closest to what you wrote.